# Is there a common place out there contains declarations for all Spring XMLs

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd

I need to write a applicationContext.xml for my Spring Framework 3 application, but I cann't find out its XML Declaration. Anyone could show me place to get it?

Likewise, is there a common place defining declarations for all Spring XMLs? (Or other XMLs being around.)

Below is a declaration example for Spring 2.5 I found out by googling:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all described in the Spring documentation see [3.2.1 Configuration metadata](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-metadata) for the basic structure and [Appendix C. XML Schema-based configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html) for details of the other declarations you could use.